# Django, админка, класс Media и js в админке, шаблонизатор

Tags: javascript, django

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ****
    class Media:
        js = ('js/sdec/str_admin.js')
```

Вот у меня есть такой простой класс OrderAdmin и простой str_admin.js. Можно ли как то сделать, так, что бы в str_admin.js я использовал конструкцию вида {% url 'tuda_suda'%} вместо "https://bla_bla.ru/tuda/suda"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, если его будет рендерить `django` как страницу.

Но нужно ли это вам. Это лишний гемор. Проще добавить в шаблоне js-переменные в теге `script`, а в js файле чекать их наличие

---

UPD:

```
{# Че нить .html #}

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.myUrlFromTemplate = '{% url "the-url" pk=object.id}';
</script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.myUrlFromTemplate !== undefined) {
        // TODO Something
        alert(window.myUrlFromTemplate);
    }
});
```

Comment: да, а как по феншую их добавить? Я например использую скрытый input. То есть не в теге <script>

Comment: обновил. что за скрытый инпут? о нем вообще не было ни слова

Comment: просто вставить в шаблон тег <input type='hidden' name='url' value={% url 'bla_bla' %}>. А потом получить его в js-файле. Не упомянул, потому что позднее пришло в голову. И насколько это уместно вообще, интересно?

Comment: вопрос реализации, никто не запретит вам делать как хотите, но скрытое поле ни к чему, ибо его можно подсмотреть. ну и еще придется искать элемент перед получением значения, вместо просто проверки наличия значения